# Jquery Code wrong

Tags: jquery

I really don t understand Why my max is always 1 .help le plz

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    let max = 0
    console.log(max)
    let game = true
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)
    console.log(random)
    $("button").click(function () {
        let input =$("input").val()

        max+=1

        console.log(max)
        console.log(input)
        if(random !== Number(input)) {
            alert("riprova")


            } else if (x === 5) {
            alert("hai perso")
        } else {
            alert("hai vinto")
        }
    })

})
```

I have no idea Why is Doing that. My let MAX is going from 0 to 1 and So on..

Comment: After 5 clicks my else of should run But It wont becouse MAX is always 1

Comment: No, [the max increments just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/yv6x9obe/1/). If you  mean the `else if (x === 5)` shouldn't you compare with `max` instead of `x`? Where is `x` defined?

Comment: Yes sry on my source code Is max === 5

Comment: Again, please read [ask] and provide an [mcve]. Something that actually works and we can check for ourselves that shows the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what was the problem.i Had in my HTML File Button tag and on every click the page reload So It start from 0. Just need too change my button with input type Button